# I'm trying to seed my DB with some products and yours datas but its fails. I'm using laravel

Tags: laravel, seeders

Error:

Illuminate\Database\QueryException

SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column 'valor' at row 1 (SQL: insert into produtos
(nome, quantidade, valor, descricao)
values (Geladeira,2,5900,Side by Side com gelo na porta))

at C:\projetos\Laravel\Estoque\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:745
741▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
742▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
743▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
744▕         catch (Exception $e) {
➜ 745▕             throw new QueryException(
746▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
747▕             );
748▕         }
749▕     }

1   C:\projetos\Laravel\Estoque\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:530
PDOException::("SQLSTATE[22003]: Numeric value out of range: 1264 Out of range value for column '

---

table:
Schema::create('produtos', function (Blueprint $table) {
$table->id();
$table->string('nome');
$table->integer('quantidade');
$table->decimal('valor', 5, 2);
$table->text('descricao');
$table->timestamps();
});

---

seed:

DB::insert('insert into produtos
(nome, quantidade, valor, descricao)
values (?,?,?,?)',
array('Geladeira', 2, 5900.00,
'Side by Side com gelo na porta')
);

```
        DB::insert('insert into produtos
            (nome, quantidade, valor, descricao)
            values (?,?,?,?)',
            array('Fogão', 5, 950.00,
            'Painel automático e forno elétrico')
        );

        DB::insert('insert into produtos
            (nome, quantidade, valor, descricao)
            values (?,?,?,?)',
            array('Microondas', 1, 1520.00,
            'Manda SMS quando termina de esquentar')
        );
```

Comment: edite e traduza a pergunta, por favor.

Answer (score -1):

O problema é que o valor 5900.00 excede o tamanho da coluna.
O primeiro número, no caso 5, informa o tamanho do número. Já o segundo, no caso 2, informa quantos desses números serão casas decimais.
Nesse caso, o formato do valor deve ser no máximo 000.00.
Para corrigir o problema, é só alterar o 5 para 6 na coluna valor, assim ela irá aceitar 0000.00.